# Busy Indicator on specific Elements (Wicket)

Tags: javascript, wicket

I'am following this guide https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=87917 and its working so far.
How can i modify this code, that i dont react globally to ajax calls anymore but instead for example only for 3 specific Buttons.

```
window.onload = setupFunc;

function setupFunc() {
    // ? $('.test').on('click',clickFunc);
    hideBusysign();
    Wicket.Event.subscribe('/ajax/call/beforeSend', function(attributes, jqXHR, settings) {
        showBusysign();
    });
    Wicket.Event.subscribe('/ajax/call/complete', function(attributes, jqXHR, textStatus) {
        hideBusysign();
    });
}

function hideBusysign() {
  $('#loader').hide();
}

function showBusysign() {
    $('#loader').show();
}

function clickFunc(eventData) {
    var clickedElement = (window.event)? event.srcElement: eventData.target;
    if ((clickedElement.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'BUTTON' || clickedElement.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'A' || clickedElement.parentNode.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'A' || (clickedElement.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'INPUT' && (clickedElement.type.toUpperCase() == 'BUTTON' || clickedElement.type.toUpperCase() == 'SUBMIT'))) && clickedElement.parentNode.id.toUpperCase() != 'NOBUSY') {

        showBusysign();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the passed `attributes` object. It has a property named `c` (for 'component') - this is the id of the HTML element that caused the Ajax call.

So you can do something like:

```
if (jQuery('#' + attributes.c).hasClass('showIndicator')) { 
    showBusysign(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement IAjaxIndicatorAware to show an Ajax indicator on a per-component basis:

https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/6.x/guide/ajax.html#ajax_4

Comment: thanks for the answer, i read the example but dont understand how this helps ? I dont want to create a new class...